# errors while Installing superset under Windows system

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-superset

I would like to install python module - superset in my Windows 10, however, some errors stop me to install further more.

After I typed in "pip install superset", Belows are the 3 errors executed in cmd:

1. Failed building wheel for python-geohash
2. flask-appbuilder 1.11.1 has requirement Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1, but
   you'll have flask-sqlalchemy 2.3.2 which is incompatible.
3. Command "c:\pythonvir\env\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import
   setuptools,
   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Lawrence\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1lqhahdp\python-geohash\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
   --record C:\Users\Lawrence\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f4lpe14x\install-record.txt
   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\pythonvir\env\include\site\python3.6\python-geohash" failed with
   error code 1 in
   C:\Users\Lawrence\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1lqhahdp\python-geohash\

Any thoughts?

I tried to install VS2015 and VS2017 and sasl, but still have error messages.

Answer (score 2):

---

### Set up Superset 0.28.1 (current pip image), instructions for Windows

- Follow instructions in [docs](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html) till just before 'pip install superset'

  - That includes 'pip install cryptography' globally.

Open command prompt in project folder:

```
:: Drop some lib versions (this is required specifically for 0.28.1 on Windows,
:: doesn't apply on current master):
pip install Pandas==0.23.4
pip install SQLAlchemy==1.2.18
:: jwt started getting specific about the flask version from 3.21.0..
pip install flask-jwt-extended==3.20.0

:: Add current folder to those searched by python for modules:
set PYTHONPATH=%cd%

python wenv\Scripts\superset db upgrade
set FLASK_APP=superset
flask fab create-admin
python wenv\Scripts\superset load_examples
python wenv\Scripts\superset init

:: Start flask devserver:
python wenv\Scripts\superset run -p 8005 --with-threads --reload --debugger
```

---

### Set up Superset by git cloning on Windows (2019-08-11)

If setting up Superset 0.34rc1 from source (using command prompt)
(taken mostly from RELEASING/Dockerfile.from_tarball, modified a few things for windows)

```
git clone <superset repo>
```

Open shell in repo folder then install and activate virtual env:

```
python -m venv wenv
:: To activate in powershell: . .\wenv\Scripts\activate
wenv\Scripts\activate
```

Need to install node to build static, just install python package 'nodeenv':

```
pip install nodeenv
```

Nodeenv is similar to virtualenv, but for managing node.

Next make node virtual env with nodeenv, placing it in a nodeenv dir:

```
nodeenv nodeenv
```

Activate node virtual env:

```
:: unlike virtualenv, nodeenv does not provide a script for activating
:: within git bash shell on windows, so we have to use command prompt
:: and convert a few commands to windows equivalents.
:: https://github.com/ekalinin/nodeenv/issues/226
:: To activate in powershell: . .\nodeenv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
nodeenv\Scripts\activate
cd superset\assets
npm ci
```

Install webpack globally:

```
npm install -g webpack webpack-cli
```

Set NODE_ENV and run webpack:

```
set NODE_ENV=production
:: Note that webpack build requires min 2048 GB of RAM,
:: and spawns many child node.js instances, each of which
:: also require copious resources. If it doesn't have enough
:: resources, the build will of course fail.
webpack --mode=production --colors --progress
```

After some time the build should complete and the files should be placed in superset/assets/dist.

```
:: Remove node_modules dir as it's no longer needed:
rmdir /q /a node_modules

:: cd back to project root
cd ..\..

:: On Windows, it appears nodeenv replaces virtualenv settings,
:: it doesn't work concurrently, so open a new shell and re-activate 
:: python env.
wenv\Scripts\activate

:: Just in case install latest pip etc.
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

:: Install project python packages
::                                         v - leave out the r, you must not.
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements-dev.txt

:: install pyodbc, if planning to connect to ms sql
pip install pyodbc

:: superset/static/assets is supposed to symlink to ../assets.
:: So we need to make a *windows symlink* or adjust setup.py..

:: Windows symlink method:
:: Open cmd.exe in admin mode or enable windows Settings / 
:: Update and Security / For developers.

:: in superset/static, rename 'assets' file.
rename assets assets_linux
:: make windows symlink
mklink assets ..\assets

:: Or modify setup.py and remove "static" from PACKAGE_DIR:
:: PACKAGE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "superset", "assets")

:: Finally, install superset in editable mode
pip install -e .

:: compile language files (gettext .po files)
fabmanager babel-compile --target superset/translations

set PATH=%cd%\superset\bin;%PATH%
IF DEFINED PYTHONPATH (set PYTHONPATH=%cd%\superset;%PYTHONPATH%) ELSE (set PYTHONPATH=%cd%\superset)
```

From here we're roughly following RELEASING\from_tarball_entrypoint.sh:

```
:: If symlink was not created for /static/assets earlier:
:: Adjust superset/config.py, line 52 so it doesn't look in the 'static' folder anymore
:: This can also be adjusted by creating a superset_config.py file that overrides config.py..
:: PACKAGE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets")

python wenv\Scripts\superset db upgrade

set FLASK_APP=superset
flask fab create-admin
python wenv\Scripts\superset load_examples
python wenv\Scripts\superset init
```

Start flask devserver:

```
:: if superset/static/assets symlink was create, static files will be correctly served..

python wenv\Scripts\superset run -p 8005 --with-threads --reload --debugger
```

---

### Set up latest Superset from git clone for Ubuntu Linux 18.04 (2019-08-11)

- Follow instructions in [docs](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html) till just before 'pip install superset'
- Including required system packages and cryptography.

  ```
  git clone <superset repo>
  ```

Open shell in repo folder then install and activate virtual env:

## use symlink to correct python binary for python 3.6+

```
python3 -m venv lenv
source lenv/bin/activate
```

Need to install node to build static, just install python package 'nodeenv':

```
pip install nodeenv
```

Nodeenv is similar to virtualenv, but for managing node.

Next make node virtual env with nodeenv, placing it in a nodeenv dir:

```
nodeenv lnenv
```

Activate node virtual env:

```
source lnenv/bin/activate
cd superset/assets
npm ci
```

Install webpack globally (globally in this case means it will go into nodeenv's virtual folder):

```
npm install -g webpack webpack-cli
npm run build
```

Finally, the build should complete and the files should be placed in superset/assets/dist.

```
# Remove node_modules dir as it's no longer needed:
rm -rf node_modules

# cd back to project root
cd ../..

# Just in case install latest pip etc.
# Use python -m pip to avoid a possible issue where some packages
# attempt to write to global python repo..
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

# Install project python packages
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements-dev.txt

# Additionally install pyodbc, if one needs to connect to ms sql
pip install pyodbc

# Install superset in editable mode
pip install -e .

# Compile language files (gettext .po files)
fabmanager babel-compile --target superset/translations

# Append to PYTHONPATH if it already exists.
export PATH=$(pwd):$PATH
if [ -z "$PYTHONPATH" ]
then
    export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd):$PYTHONPATH
else
    export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)
fi 
# Can also adjust SUPERSET_HOME to store default sqlite db in a different place.
# export SUPERSET_HOME=$(pwd)/superset_home
export MAPBOX_API_KEY=your_mapbox_key...
```

From here we're roughly following RELEASES\from_tarball_entrypoint.sh:

```
superset db upgrade

export FLASK_APP=superset
flask fab create-admin
superset load_examples
superset init
```

Start flask devserver:

```
superset run -p 8005 --with-threads --reload --debugger
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while installing superset. The problem is Windows: I could install the python-geohash library following the next steps:

1. For the Flask-SQLAlchemy, install this library again, but specify the version you need: `pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy=2.1`
2. For the python-geohash library: First download the .whl from the 'Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages' webpage: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-geohash](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#python-geohash).
   Then, download the .whl that satisfies your python version. Then, install the package using this command:

   ```
   pip install <path_to_the_file>\<name_of_package>.whl
   ```

Finally, try again the installation of superset.